# Does dnf5 support parallel metadata downloads? How do I make it?

Tags: package-management, dnf, dnf5

I'm pretty happily using `dnf5` on my fedora 38. It's both a new library for dependency resolution and a new frontend, replacing `dnf`/`libdnf` (though nearly completely drop-in compatible with the CLI of `dnf`).

It's much faster at doing things like searching the package database for words, so that's refreshing. Speaking of refreshing:

Can I configure `dnf5` to download metadata from different remote repositories (Fedora 38, Fedora 38, updates, Fedora 38 openh264, Fedora 38 nonfree updates, rpm fusion updates, rpm fusion non-free updates …) in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, but there is an issue tracking that feature.

https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf5/issues/307

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it seems to be harder to do multiple downloads asynchronously than theoretically possbile; but I can fully get why librepo's design wasn't keen on fully utilizing all the hmm beauty of GMainContext-based asynchronous working.